# Cannot type text after some interraction in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried automate sending solution to codewars
So when i am clicking to kata page, typing in code field is avialable, but after clicking one element to find previous solution, selenium throws an exception:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://codewars.com")

assert driver.title == "Codewars - Achieve mastery through coding practice and developer mentorship"


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="(//a[@id='login-btn'])[2]").click()
# Authorization
driver.find_element(By.ID, value="user_email").send_keys("email")
driver.find_element(By.ID, value="user_password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//button[normalize-space()='Sign in']").click()

# Accessing search page
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//nav[@id='sidenav']//li[3]//a[1]").click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#ids_filter").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[value="not_completed"]').click()

# Finding kata
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Regex Password Validation").click()
sleep(1)
# replaying kata
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="replay_btn"]').click()
sleep(2)

solution = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="code"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/textarea')
# typing is avialable
solution.send_keys("here i can type")
# finding previous answer, clicking "past solutions"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="description_area"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/a').click()
answer = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                             '//*[@id="description_area"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/pre/code/span[3]').text
print(answer)

# Here is problem
solution.send_keys("here i can't type")


sleep(5555)
```

[Tag to access text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7UjI.png)

I don't understand why typing is not avialable after interracting other element. Also i can't even click on this element, it throws same exception.